# What is the point of Lester's "Locate a car"?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

As the title says, what's the point of Lester locating a car for you?  It's the same vehicle, in the same place every time for me (an ATV at the race track).

I've seen suggestions that it's so that you can get a vehicle that's not stolen, but if you have to go to a specific place to pick it up then it's pointless.  I may as well just go to my garage and get a car there.

I was (as were most people) under the incorrect impression that you would be able to specify what car type you were looking for, which would be **great** for collecting high value cars for Simeon, so it's disappointing.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: possibly a broken feature that is not yet important enough to focus on. pretty sure the same thing happens with boats.

Comment: @turbo I strongly suspect you're correct.  Hopefully we'll get something solid on this.  I suspect that the imminent $250,000 will make me forget about this for a while :p

Comment: they can keep their money, my RP and cash haven't been saving since 1.04 was released.  Played 4-5 hours yesterday to level 41. Logged back on, reset to 34, 150k or so gone.

Comment: I've had the same problem, but on and off.  The most shocking issue was when I went to my friends list and it was empty!  A quick search showed a LOT of people had that after the 1.04 update.  Thankfully a reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is to locate a vehicle that won't give you wanted stars or give you a bounty for stealing it.

The feature definitely seems bugged, as that ATV is commonly what has been located for me, even if it is halfway across the map from my current location. You would expect the vehicle that is located would be in some close proximity to you

Comment: Yeah, that would make some sense.  At the moment I'm obviously calling my mechanic and getting my own car delivered to me, rather than traipsing half way across the map to get a vehicle that'll kill me the first time I crash.